# How do I test whether a variable is defined before referencing it?

Tags: scheme

I would like to be able to test whether a variable is defined, prior to accessing it.

I like to have a global that specifies a "debug level". If debug level is 0, no extra output is given. When greater than 1, debug output is given, with more verbosity at greater numbers.

I also would like to set it up so that the procedures would run, and assume a level 0, if I had not gotten around to defining it. Something like: (where `defined?` is the magic I don't know how to do?

```
(if (and (defined? debug-level) (> debug-level 1))
    (diplay "Some debugging info"))
```

I have looked through the summary of forms in [*The Scheme Programming Language, 4th Edition*](http://scheme.com/tspl4/summary.html#./summary:h0). The only one that I saw as a possibility was `identifier?`. It did not work.

I'm using SISC 1.16.6 (claims R5RS compliance) and Chez Petite Scheme v8 (claims R6RS compliance)

**EDIT** I tried wrapping `eval` with a `guard` like:

```
(guard (x (else #f)) (eval 'debug-level))
```

Since `'debug-level` is quoted it can be evaluated and passed to `eval`. Then when `eval` tries to evaluate it, an error would happen, which I hoped `guard` would catch. It didn't.

**EDIT 2** I realized that I wanted to wrap the debug tracing into a seperate procedure and that the file that defines that procedure can also define `debug-level` with a default of 0. The reasons for using a seperate procedure are to lower the number of lines in the procedures that do work and also to allow the redirection of debug output if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is totally up to the implementation to provide, and it looks like most implementations don't satisfactorily provide it.

In SISC scheme, it looks like you can use [GETPROP](http://sisc-scheme.org/manual/html/ch03.html#SymbolicEnvironments) to this effect, <del>but environments don't update automatically</del> oh, look, there's this thing called INTERACTION-ENVIRONMENT that you can use:

```
#;> (getprop 'cons (interaction-environment))
#<native procedure cons>
#;> (getprop 'x (interaction-environment))
#f
#;> (define x 100)
#;> (getprop 'x (interaction-environment))
100
```

But it only works on the top level.

```
#;> (define (foo y)
  (let ((e (interaction-environment)))
    (display "Is X bound? ") (display (getprop 'x e))
    (newline)
    (display "Is Y bound? ") (display (getprop 'y e))
    (newline) ))
#;> (foo 1)
#;> Is X bound? 100
Is Y bound? #f
```

For Chez you have [TOP-LEVEL-BOUND?](http://www.scheme.com/csug8/binding.html#./binding:h5) and INTERACTION-ENVIRONMENT again.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid the answer would not be widely portable, that it would be either something new in R6RS or implementation specific. +1, but I'm going to let this answer age a bit, to see if any better ideas get posted before accepting as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Clunky but workable solution for R5RS. Use the often neglect/forgotten ability of let-syntax to redefine keywords.  this is clunky because your whole file is wrapped in a let-syntax and because it adds some overhead to each define.  I use a associative list to remember definitions, a hash table would be a beter choice.

```
(define define-list '())
(define define-list-add 
  (lambda (key value)
    (set! define-list (cons `(,key ,value) define-list))))

(let-syntax (
             (define (syntax-rules ()
                       ((_ (pro-name args ...) body ...) 
                        (begin
                          (define (pro-name args ...) body ...)
                          (define-list-add pro-name  '((pro-name args ...) body ...))))
                       ((_ pro-name pro) (begin
                                           (define pro-name pro)
                                           (define-list-add 'pro-name 'pro)))

                       ))
             (defined?
               (syntax-rules ()
                 ((_ sym) (begin (if (assoc (quote sym) define-list) #t #f)))))
             )
  (define y (lambda () x))

  (display (defined? y))
  (newline)
  (display (defined? x))
  )
```

prints

```
#t
#f
```

Below in racket: a module is used to redefine define to store each symbol and definition in a list called define-list.  The macro defined? looks in this list to see if weather or not the symbol has been defined.

```
(module qdefine mzscheme
  (provide ;(all-from-except mzscheme let)
   (rename define olddefine)
   (rename quote-define define)
   defined?)

  (define define-list '())
  (define define-list-add 
    (lambda (key value)
      (set! define-list (cons `(,key ,value) define-list))))

  (define-syntax quote-define
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ (pro-name args ...) body ...) 
       (begin
         (define (pro-name args ...) body ...)
         (define-list-add pro-name  '((pro-name args ...) body ...))))
      ((_ pro-name pro) (begin
                          (define pro-name pro)
                          (define-list-add 'pro-name 'pro)))

      ))

  (define-syntax defined?
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ sym) (begin (if (assoc (quote sym) define-list) #t #f)))))
  )
(require 'qdefine)

(define y (lambda () x))

(defined? y)
(defined? x)
```

In guile it is just defined? apparently:
http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/guile/guile_289.html

Comment: Racket does have the reflection tools to do something like this, but such things (including `interaction-environment`, whatever Guile does, etc) are always shaky kind of solutions, which suffer one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

To back up a bit, the problem with a `defined?` function is that if you write

```
(defined? debug-level)
```

Scheme will attempt to evaluate `debug-level`, which of course is an error since it is not defined. Such a form would have to be implemented internally by the compiler/interpreter as a special case.

Such a special form is not part of the R5RS standard (unless I missed it, please [double-check](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-2.html#%_toc_start)). So with regard to R5RS schemes you are out of luck unless you find a Scheme that implements this as a non-standard extension.

Comment: I was not asking for a function `defined?` because, as you say, a function would not work. But a function would not work for `if` either, and yet scheme has `if`. In other workds, looking for a special form, or other way of achieving the results. (Macro maybe?)

Comment: Sure. What I was trying to say is that this would have to be one of the built-in forms that the language provides, such as `if`, and the spec (R5RS at least) does not seem to include one.