# How to know whether a racket variable is defined or not

Tags: variables, racket, defined

How you can have a different behaviour if a variable is defined or not in racket language?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Are you trying to use an undefined variable somewhere? I couldn't get your question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267351/how-do-i-test-whether-a-variable-is-defined-before-referencing-it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  But I suspect that none of these is what you want, so I'll only provide pointers to the functions (and explain the problems with each one):

1. [`namespace-variable-value`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._namespace-variable-value%29%29) is a function that retrieves the value of a toplevel variable from some namespace.  This is useful only with REPL interaction and REPL code though, since code that is defined in a module is not going to use these things anyway.  In other words, you can use this function (and the corresponding `namespace-set-variable-value!`) to get values (if any) and set them, but the only use of these values is in code that is not itself in a module.  To put this differently, using this facility is as good as keeping a hash table that maps symbols to values, only it's slightly more convenient at the REPL since you just type names...
2. More likely, these kind of things are done in macros.  The first way to do this is to use the special [`#%top`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/__top.html#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._~23~25top%29%29) macro.  This macro gets inserted automatically for all names in a module that are not known to be bound.  The usual thing that this macro does is throw an error, but you can redefine it in your code (or make up your own language that redefines it) that does something else with these unknown names.
3. A slightly more sophisticated way to do this is to use the [`identifier-binding`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxcmp.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._identifier-binding%29%29) function -- again, in a *macro*, not at runtime -- and use it to get information about some name that is given to the macro and decide what to expand to based on that name.

The last two options are the more useful ones, but they're not the newbie-level kind of macros, which is why I suspect that you're asking the wrong question.  To clarify, you can use them to write a kind of a `defined?` special form that checks whether some name is defined, but that question is one that would be answered by a macro, based on the rest of the code, so it's not really useful to ask it.  If you want something like that that can enable the kind of code in other dynamic languages where you use such a predicate, then the best way to go about this is to redefine `#%top` to do some kind of a lookup (hashtable or global namespace) instead of throwing a compilation error -- but again, the difference between that and using a hash table explicitly is mostly cosmetic (and again, this is not a newbie thing).

Comment: For things that work only in the REPL, one can also simply catch the `exn:fail:contract:variable?` exception.

Comment: Yeah, but this is less fit for newbie uses, since (a) you'll need to wrap every top level interaction with the exception catching code, once you catch it, there is no way to "jump back" to the exception location with some other value, so still the only thing you can do is to abort the interaction.

Answer (score 9):

First, read Eli's answer. Then, based on Eli's answer, you can implement the `defined?` macro this way:

```
#lang racket

; The macro
(define-syntax (defined? stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ id)
     (with-syntax ([v (identifier-binding #'id)])
       #''v)]))

; Tests
(define x 3)
(if (defined? x) 'defined 'not-defined) ; -> defined

(let ([y 4])
   (if (defined? y) 'defined 'not-defined)) ; -> defined

(if (defined? z) 'defined 'not-defined) ; -> not-defined
```

It works for this basic case, but it has a problem: if `z` is undefined, the branch of the `if` that considers that it is defined and uses its value will raise a compile-time error, because the normal `if` checks its condition value at run-time (dynamically):

```
; This doesn't work because z in `(list z)' is undefined:
(if (defined? z) (list z) 'not-defined)
```

So what you probably want is a `if-defined` macro, that tells at compile-time (instead of at run-time) what branch of the `if` to take:

```
#lang racket

; The macro
(define-syntax (if-defined stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ id iftrue iffalse)
     (let ([where (identifier-binding #'id)])
       (if where #'iftrue #'iffalse))]))

; Tests
(if-defined z (list z) 'not-defined) ; -> not-defined

(if-defined t (void) (define t 5))
t ; -> 5

(define x 3)
(if-defined x (void) (define x 6))
x ; -> 3
```